# Query XML Document with Namespaces

Tags: xml

I have a snippet of an XML file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfCatalogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CatalogItem>
        <ID xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices">bbe9b897-5d3b-4340-914b-fce8d6022bd9</ID>
        <Name xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices">EmployeeReport</Name>
    </CatalogItem>
```

Now I'm trying to query the file for all the Name elements.  I'm aware that I can use the `SelectNodes("//Name")` to give me what I want. However, since I have namespaces in the `<ArrayOfCatalogItem>` I have to account for that. So here's the code I have so far:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\CatalogItems.xml");

// Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces
System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodeList;
System.Xml.XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Name", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} items.", nodeList.Count);
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode item in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

However, the problem I'm having is the namespace definitions in the `<Name>` tag.  How would I query the document for all Name values taking into account each `<Name>` has a namespace defined as an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong XML namespace - you need to use the one that is applied to the `<Name>` tag - not the document default namespaces (`xsd:` and `xsi:` prefixes).

Try this:

```
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\CatalogItems.xml");

// Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices");

XmlNodeList nodeList;
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//rs:Name", nsmgr);

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} items.", nodeList.Count);

foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: That worked.  However, when using the AddNamespace in your code, the first parameter is "rs".  But that isn't defined anywhere in the document.  It does work, but now I don't understand *why* it works.

Comment: @Coson: that's just an **arbitrary** XML namespace prefix that you define **in your code** - it has **no relation whatsoever** with the document - it's just **your way** in **your code** to define a prefix for the XML namespace. The only thing that **MUST** match is the actual XML namespace, of course! But the prefix is totally independent of the underlying XML document...

Comment: That worked.  At first, I was initially confused about the first parameter of the AddNamespace method because I didn't see "rs" defined anywhere in the document.  So I'm guessing that you can use any thing you want since the namespace wasn't specified.  By changing "rs" to "test" in both locations, it appeared to work.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, my browser didn't refresh properly.  Now I'm good.