# parsing vcxproj with System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to parse a vcxproj file using powershell (actually with .NET class System.Xml.XmlDocument). The problem seems to be somehow related with the xmlns attribute of the root element - see example xml file below (extract of original xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

With powershell I open the xml file and want to select some nodes. But this actually does not return any node.

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load("/path/to/xml/file")
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//ProjectConfiguration")
```

I already tried to add a namespace manager, but that didn't help:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load("/path/to/xml/file")
$mgr=new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.Psbase.NameTable)
$mgr.AddNamespace("gr",$xml.configuration.psbase.NamespaceURI)
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//ProjectConfiguration")
```

If I remove the xmlns attribute of the root element, everything works fine.

Regards,
Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an example in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283774) that I adapted to this PowerShell:

```
$inputstring = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
'@
$xpath = "/rs:Project/rs:ItemGroup/rs:ProjectConfiguration"
$xmldoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmldoc.LoadXml($inputstring)
# !!USE xmldoc.load if you want to load from a file instead

# Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces
$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xmldoc.NameTable);
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

$root = $xmldoc.DocumentElement
$nodes = $root.SelectNodes($xpath, $nsmgr)

$outputstring = "Found " + $nodes.Count + " item(s)"
write-host $outputstring
```

The output I get is:

```
Found 2 item(s)
```

Comment: Thanks man, that solved my problem! Maybe only for clarification: Are all nodes automatically (implicitly) prefixed with the namespace identifier? Even if `<ItemGroup>` is written, it resolves to `<rs:ItemGroup>`?